# Asyncio Transport and Protocols stream data received into a bytearray for processing

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I"m following the example in [TCP Client/Server](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client), but i'm having trouble piping the results from `data_received` into my other functions for processing down the line.

By reproducing their example in my `FactoryTCP.py` file, and calling `loop.create_connection` from my `main.py` file, I am able to establish a connection to the server and send 1 message, and get the reply.

However, this reply, is printed from `FactoryTCP.py` file, and not streamed / piped into `main.py` file. Ideally, I would like for the data that is being received, to be streamed / piped into a `bytesarray` so that I can further manipulate it.

This is an example of what I have:

**FactoryTCP.py**

```
class ProtocolFactoryTCP(Transport, Protocol):

    def __init__(self,  on_con_lost, main_buffer):
        super().__init__()
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost
        self.transport = None
        self.main_buffer = main_buffer  # I had thought that my initializing this, 
                                        # I can extend into it and receive the file from `main.py`. 
                                        # But this is not the case.

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)
        print('The server | client closed the connection')

    def data_received(self, data):
        print(f'Data received: {data}, {self.transport.get_extra_info("peername")}')

    def eof_received(self):
        print("end of file received.")
```

**main.py**

```
async def main():

    main_buffer = bytesarray()
    on_con_lost = event_loop.create_future()
    connection = ProtocolFactoryTCP(on_con_lost, main_buffer)
    transport, protocol = await event_loop.create_connection(lambda: connection, "peer_ip", "peer_port")

    print('reading transport', transport.is_reading())
    print('writing transport', transport.write(message))  # Just a test to see if i can write outside. It works.
    print('writing transport', transport.write(extra_msg))  # Just a test to see if i can write outside. It works.

    try:
        await on_con_lost
        print('awaiting for con lost')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

With this current code, I am able to send messages outside of `ProtocolFactoryTCP`, but how do I get my hands on the `data_received` outside of `ProtocolFactoryTCP` as well? This is so that I can create different handlers and functions to deal with the result and respond back to it while the connection is not broken.

Comment: main accepts a 'self' parameter, but you don't pass it when calling it.

Comment: Oh i was testing it within a class. Forgot to remove it while I was pasting to stackoverflow. i've removed it.

Comment: may I assume that loop and event_loop (in main) are "asyncio.get_event_loop()"?

Comment: Hi Roy2012, yea it is. I've also added it in for clarity.

Comment: I played with the code. Calling  self.main_buffer.extend(data) in 'data_received' does the trick. The data can then be used in main. Is that what you're looking for, or is there more to it?

Comment: Hmm, but where in `main` do you call for `self.main_buffer`? I was trying it immediately after `print('writing transport', transport.write(extra_msg))` but it doesn't. Show. Sorry, quite new to asyncio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Shared variable solution

I changed `data_received` and `main` and as follows:

```
def data_received(self, data):
    extra = self.transport.get_extra_info("peername")
    print( f"Data received: {data}, {extra}" )
    self.main_buffer.extend(data) # share the data with the rest of the world
```

in main, I'm printing the data when I know it's there:

```
try:
    await on_con_lost
    print('awaiting for con lost')
    print(main_buffer)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

That's one way to transfer data between the protocol factory and the rest of the application - but there are other, more elegant ways.

One such way is to give the factory a callback to call whenever data comes in. Then, instead of printing the data or appending it to the buffer, `data_received` will call this callback.

### Callback solution.

Here's the code of the callback solution:

```
class ProtocolFactoryTCP(Transport, Protocol):

    def __init__(self,  on_con_lost, main_buffer, callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost
        self.transport = None
        self.callback = callback
        self.main_buffer = main_buffer  

    def data_received(self, data):
        extra = self.transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        print( f"Data received: {data}, {extra}" )
        self.main_buffer.extend(data)
        self.callback(self.transport, data) 

...

def my_callback(transport, data):
    print(f"in the callback. data is {data}")
    print('writing transport', transport.write(b"hello, again")) 

... 

async def main():

    ...
    connection = ProtocolFactoryTCP(on_con_lost, main_buffer, my_callback)
```

To make it work, you'll also have to comment out / remove the two lines in the server, to prevent it from closing the connection immediately:

```
#        print('Close the client socket')
#        self.transport.close()
```

#### An async callback solution

A variant of the above would be to make `my_callback` async. To demo that, change the following two lines:

```
async def my_callback(transport, data):
===== Make my_callback async
```

In `data_received`, instead of just calling `my_callback`, schedule it as a task:

```
asyncio.create_task(self.callback(self.transport, data))
```

Comment: Thanks for this Roy. However, i think this will also mean that I'll only get the data after the connection has been closed right? Then it kinda means that I won't be able to send other responses back to the server to get other data, etc. The callback added to `data_received` sounds interesting, I'll probably check that out more to see if it fits my purpose. Or do u also have an example for callbacks?

Comment: Nice one Roy. The async callback was a nice touch. :)